# wpf binding combobox selectedvaluepath

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a list of type string(selectedextensionvalue) in my viewmodel. How can I bind selectedvaluepath(which is also of type list string) of my combobox to selectedextensionvalue. I don't know the syntax. May anyone help?

Thanks in advance,
Bilge

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of strings, so you do not need to use `SelectedValuePath` property. You can add some string field to your `ViewModel` of string type.

```
public string SelectedStringValue
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

and in xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=selectedextensionvalue}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStringValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

**EDIT:**

But, if you want `ComboBox` to select some special item (for example, which you store in the database), so property `SelectedStringValue` should to raise `PropertyChanged` notification in setter, and the xaml will be the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=selectedextensionvalue}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStringValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```